# Find keys in multidimensional dict based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts that looks like the following:

```
{ 'a':{'foo': True,
       'bar': 1,
       'baz': 'abc'},
  'b':{'foo': True,
       'bar': 21,
       'baz': 'abc'},
  'c':{'foo': True,
       'bar': 3,
       'baz': 'cba'}}
```

What is the most efficient way to filter the dict to only include those keys whose sub-values for 'baz' are 'abc'?  So in the example above, it would return a dict that looked like:

```
{ 'a':{'foo': True,
       'bar': 1,
       'baz': 'abc'},
  'b':{'foo': True,
       'bar': 21,
       'baz': 'abc'}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v['baz'] == 'abc'}
```

Comment: for python 2, `dict( (k,v) for k, v in my_dict.items() if v['baz'] == 'abc' )`

Comment: @Dan: specifically, Python 2.6 and below (the dict coprehension syntax has been backported to 2.7).