# Get key for dict if the search item in value (value is a list)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict as below

```
{"low":[18,12,9],"medium":[6,3],"high":[2,1],"final":[0]}
```

and I want to search for a number in this dict and get its respective 'key'

Eg: for 12, i need to return 'low'. slly for 2, return 'high'

Comment: which python version you are using ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459707/find-keys-in-multidimensional-dict-based-on-value

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* for this.

```
dict = {"low":[18,12,9],"medium":[6,3],"high":[2,1],"final":[0]}
key = {k:v for k, v in dict.items() if 12 in v}
```

Output

```
In[1]: key.popitem()[0]
Out[1] : 12
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `next`.

```
my_d = {"low":[18,12,9],"medium":[6,3],"high":[2,1],"final":[0]}

target = 12
res = next((k for k, v in my_d.items() if target in v), 'N\A')
print(res)  # low
```

Note that if your `target` value exists in more than one keys, this code will return one of them at *random<sup>1</sup>*. If that might by the case and depending on the problem you are working on it may be wiser to get all matching keys instead. To do that, use:

```
res = [k for k, v in my_d.items() if target in v]
```

<sup>1</sup>Actually more like *in an uncontrolled fashion*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getKey(number):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():   
        if number in value:
            return key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {"low":[18,12,9],"medium":[6,3],"high":[2,1],"final":[0]}



def search_key(val):
    for key, value in dict.iteritems():
        for i in value:
            if i == val:
                print "the key is:"+key
                return key

#pass any value for which you want to get the key
search_key(9)
```